# Time of first train from Rosas station to Valencia airport by Metro

Tags: trains, valencia

Where or how can I find the time of the first train from Rosas Metro station to Valencia airport?

Answer (score 4):

First metro from Rosas leaves at 5:20AM and arrives to Airport station at 5:22AM.

[image: Metro timetable from Rosas to Airport]

Source: [Metrovalencia](http://www.metrovalencia.es/horarios.php?idioma=_en)